# WebRequestContext.IsPreview

Tags: dxa, experience-manager

Where do we get the value for WebRequestContext.IsPreview filled?
We are trying to use like (from DXA view)
@if (WebRequestContext.IsPreview)
{
    // code here - never getting executed
}
This is for Staging where we enabled inline editing. With this "SDL Tridion" button is not seen on the staging web site.

Comment: I'm not sure what your last sentence means but `.isPreview` returns whether the context is Staging. Are you trying to show or hide the "SDL Tridion" (start Experience Manager) button?

Comment: Yes @AlvinReyes, we wanted to see "SDL Tridion" button. We are seeing "staging": true in _all.json but still not able to see the button.

Comment: Check if your CMS Url is correct in the generated markup, and also if you can reach that url from your browser. Could very well be that your browser can't load the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.DxaPageMarkup()
```

is responsible for rendering the (SDL Tridion/Site Edit Icon) button for staging websites. 
    Please check whether you have that line of code is available in your cshtml pages.